# Notification Action does not open Service

Tags: android, service, android-service, wear-os

I'm trying to make a feature in my application that lets the user speak words in his wearable. This works and it works when receiving the data in an activity. Only now I want to receive the data in a service, but that doesn't seem to work. The service isn't launched at all.

code to make the notification for the wearable:

```
            String replyLabel = "Adres";

        RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder("ADDRESS")
                .setLabel(replyLabel)
                .build();

        RemoteInput remoteInput2 = new RemoteInput.Builder("PLACE")
                .setLabel("Plaats van levering")
                .build();

        Intent replyIntent = new Intent(this, LogisticWearableListener.class);
        PendingIntent replyPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, replyIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Action action =
                new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.lzicon,
                        getString(R.string.wearable_input_start), replyPendingIntent)
                        .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                        .addRemoteInput(remoteInput2)
                        .build();

        Notification notification =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(logisticLoginInfoScreen)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.lzicon)
                        .setContentIntent(replyPendingIntent)
                        .setContentTitle("Order invoeren")
                        .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addAction(action))
                        .build();

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(logisticLoginInfoScreen);
        notificationManager.notify(55, notification);
```

This is the Service code:

```
public class LogisticWearableListener extends IntentService {
private String datum;
private String adres;
private LogisticAndroidApp app;

public LogisticWearableListener() {
    super("LogisticWearableListener");
    Log.d("called wearableserv", "called");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("LogisticWearableService", "Service Received.");
        app = (LogisticAndroidApp)getApplication();
        Bundle remoteInput = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent);
        if (remoteInput != null) {
            CharSequence seq = remoteInput.getCharSequence("PLACE");
            datum = seq.toString();
            adres = remoteInput.getCharSequence("ADDRESS").toString();
            WearableOrder o = new WearableOrder();
            o.setAdres(adres);
            o.setPlace(datum);
            app.getDataManager().saveWearableOrder(o);
            //orders.add(o);
            //  initializeListView();
        }

    }
}
```

and android manifest declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.afc.mobile365.Test4Sure"
android:versionCode="222"
android:versionName="3.8.71">

<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="23"
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"></supports-screens>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".LogisticAndroidApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/lzicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    tools:replace="android:icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".LogisticActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LogisticLoginInfoScreen"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StartWorkDayActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PlanningOrdersActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StopWorkDayActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StartWorkDayInfoActivity"
        android:noHistory="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DeliveryListActivity"
        android:noHistory="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DeliveryDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LogisticInfoActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WisselActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CustomerSigningActivity"
        android:noHistory="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LogisticScanTagsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

        <!-- android:noHistory="true" -->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PauzeActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StopPauzeActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CameraActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>

    <service android:name="com.teamviewer.sdk.screensharing.api.TVSessionService" />
    <service
        android:name=".LogisticDBManagerService"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/service_name"
        android:process=":logistic_background" />
    <service
        android:name=".LogisticDBGpsLocatieService"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="locationService" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".LogisticServiceStartupReceiver"
        android:process=":logistic_background">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":logistic_background" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".ATimeReceiver"
        android:process=":logistic_background2" />
    <receiver android:name=".FotoUploadAlarmReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name=".LocationChangedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="logistic.android.app.gps"></action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".NavigationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CacheFotosActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cache_fotos"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OrderRegelActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bon"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OrderRegelOverviewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_order_regel_overview"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OrderRegelCheckboxActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_order_regel_checkbox"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EmballageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_emballage"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DialogActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dialog"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ScanTestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_scan_test"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LogisticScanEmbaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_logistic_scan_emba"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TankRegistratieActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tank_registratie"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LaadLijstEmballageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_laad_lijst_emballage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TestScanActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test_scan"></activity>

    <!-- Register Service -->
    <activity
        android:name=".LaadLijstOntvangEmballageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_laad_lijst_ontvang_emballage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"></activity>
    <!--
         ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
         App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".Wearable.WearableActivity" android:label="Plaats Order"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Logistic"></activity>
</application>

<service android:name=".LogisticWearableListener" android:exported="true">
</service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Service` needs to be "exported" so that other components (in this case, the `NotificationManager`) can start it.

Add `android:exported="true"` to the manifest entry for your `Service`.

Comment: Are there any errors in the logcat? Don't filter the logcat otherwise you might miss something important. Is your Service getting started? Did you add any logging?

Comment: Nope, doesn't show anything. I do see logs of other services I got running in the app so I think it's never being called.

Comment: Your manifest entry for your service needs to be inside the application tag. You have it outside the application tag.